# Use local storage to take time in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I was wondering how to **take time in milliseconds using local storage**,
**I want to take the time from that moment when the animation stops until the user presses either B or R**, The test is 50 different files and a Result file so I'm just going to post two of the files and the result file, here is my code so far:

Test1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test1</title>
<style>
body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
#first-child {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: white;
   border-radius: 100%;
   margin-top: 150px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 550px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
   -moz-animation: myfirst 1s;
   animation: myfirst 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
        0% {background: white;}
       20% {background: white;}
       40% {background: white;}
       60% {background: white;}
       80% {background: white;}
      100% {background: red;}
}
@keyframes myfirst {
        0% {background: white;}
       20% {background: white;}
       40% {background: white;}
       60% {background: white;}
       80% {background: white;}
      100% {background: red;}
}
#first-parent {
   color: blue;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 600px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}
#second-parent {
   color: red;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 40px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}

p {
   margin-left: 640px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="first-child"></div>

<div>
<button id="first-parent" onclick="">B</button>
<button id="second-parent">R</button>
</div>

<br />
<p>1/50</p>

<script>
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode,
   character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

   var answer;
   if(e.charCode == 98 || e.keyCode == 98) {
      answer = "B";
   } else if(e.charCode == 114 || e.keyCode == 114) {
      answer = "R";
   } else {
      alert("Press B or R to continue");
      return false;
   }

   localStorage.setItem("keypressed", "");
   localStorage.setItem("keypressed", "<h3>Test 1</h3>Your Answer: " + answer + "<br /> 

   Correct Answer: R<hr>");
   window.location.href="Test2.html";
   return true;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test2</title>
<style>
body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
#first-child {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: white;
   border-radius: 0%;
   margin-top: 150px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 550px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s;
   -moz-animation: myfirst 1s;
   animation: myfirst 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
        0% {background: white;}
       20% {background: white;}
       40% {background: white;}
       60% {background: white;}
       80% {background: white;}
      100% {background: blue;}
}
@keyframes myfirst {
        0% {background: white;}
       20% {background: white;}
       40% {background: white;}
       60% {background: white;}
       80% {background: white;}
      100% {background: blue;}
}
#first-parent {
   color: blue;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 600px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}
#second-parent {
   color: red;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 40px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}

p {
   margin-left: 640px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="first-child"></div>

<div>
<button id="first-parent">B</button>
<button id="second-parent">R</button>
</div>

<br />
<p>2/50</p>

<script>
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode,
   character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

   var answer;
   if(e.charCode == 98 || e.keyCode == 98) {
      answer = "B";
   } else if(e.charCode == 114 || e.keyCode == 114) {
      answer = "R";
   } else {
      alert("Press B or R to continue");
      return false;
   }

   var res = localStorage.getItem("keypressed");
   res+= "<h3>Test 2</h3>Your Answer: " + answer + "<br /> Correct Answer: B<hr>";
   localStorage.setItem("keypressed", res);
   window.location.href="Test3.html";
   return true;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Result</title>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>
<script>

</script>
</div>

<script>
var result = localStorage.getItem("keypressed");
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And that was it I know HTML, jQuery and JavaScript so no PHP solutions, thanks in advance, peace !

Comment: It's not really clear here what the actual problem is?  Is it simply how to get  a millisecond timer in Javascript, or is it related to Local Storage?

Comment: Sorry about that, um I wan't to take time in milliseconds using local storage

Comment: I'm still not really clear on what the problem is though?  You get milliseconds from a date object and you get/put things into local storage using the local storage API.  Which part of that is the problem?  Generally you don't get great answers on SO unless you can show a partial solution and highlight where it's not working.

Comment: What actually you want ? you want to get the file name from local storage and load that file as inner html to your result div or something else

Comment: So now I have updated it I forgoted to write what I really wanted, sorry

Comment: If it's still not clear I want to take the time in milliseconds from that moment when the animation stops until the user presses either B or R.

Answer (score 0):

You get the current millisecond count using the .getTime() method on a date object. So just create a date object at both points in time that you are interested in and take the difference.

```
var start = new Date();
.... do stuff...
var end = new Date();
var timeInMilliseconds = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
```

I'm not sure exactly when "when the animation stops" is.  If it's related to when a CSS animation finishes you may have problems as a javascript event is not raised at that point (as far as I know). So there is no way to hook some code in to that point in time to create a date object.

You could switch to using javascript animations (e.g. jquery) or just assume the animation takes a fixed amount of time every time.

EDIT: A quick bit of Googling brings up a few possible ways of detecting a CSS animation ending in JS, e.g. http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback

Looks promising...

Comment: It's related to the css animation, I want to take the time when the css animation ends until someone presses B or R. You know what I mean ?

Comment: Yes, the link in my edit relates to detecting the end of a css animation in javascript.  There are a few other sources on Google.  I'd try them out and if you get stuck on a specific point raise a question on it.  You're unlikely to get someone to post the full source for a solution here.